# Sql server bulk delete by known record ids

Tags: sql-server, merge, delete-row, sql-delete, bulk

I need to delete many rows from sql server 2008 database, it must be scalable so I was thinking about bulk delete, the problem is that the are not many references on this, at least in my case.

The first factor is that I will exactly know the ID of every row to delete, so any tips with TOP are not an option, also I will delete less rows that I want to retain so there will be no need for some "drop/temp table/re-create" methods.

So I was thinking to use WHERE IN , either suppling IDs or xml data with IDs, there is also an option to use MERGE to delete rows.

If I will have to delete 1000+ rows, sending all ids to WHERE IN could be a problem ? And what with MERGE - it is really a cure for all bulk insert/update/delete problems? What to choose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to store the known ID's into a "controller" table, and then delete rows from your main data table that have their ID show up in the controller table.

That way, you could easily "batch" up your deletes, e.g.

```
DELETE FROM dbo.YourMainDataTable
WHERE ID IN (SELECT TOP (250) ID FROM dbo.DeleteControllerTable)
```

You could easily run this delete statement in e.g. a SQL Agent Job which comes around every 15 minutes to check if there's anything to delete. In the meantime, you could add more ID's to your `DeleteController` table, thus you could "decouple" the process of entering the ID's to be deleted from the actual deletion process.

Comment: Yeh i was thinking about it also, but 250 rows per 15 minutes could be to less quickly, could there be some performance issues with WHERE IN when i will select to delete for example TOP 1k to 3k rows ?

Comment: @Programista: deleting large numbers of rows is **always** a performance issue - there's no way around that (except for not deleting). Whether you delete 250 or 1000 or 3000 at a time is up to you - try it, measure the performance, decide what to do. There's no magic formula to find out how many you can delete - you need to find out yourself, on your system, under your workload.

Comment: @Programista - To avoid lock escalation I think 5000 is the magic number.